# Spring REST - How can I retrieve the id of the returned resource?

Tags: spring, rest

I have an integration test that is successful but I would like to add into it.

```
@Test
public void testAdd() throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Common.createAuthenticationHeaders("stephane" + ":" + PASSWORD);

    this.mockMvc.perform(
        post("/admin").headers(httpHeaders)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("{ \"firstname\" : \"" + admin0.getFirstname() + "\", \"lastname\" : \"" + admin0.getLastname() + "\", \"email\" : \"" + admin0.getEmail() + "\", \"login\" : \"" + admin0.getLogin() + "\", \"password\" : \"" + admin0.getPassword() + "\", \"passwordSalt\" : \"" + admin0.getPasswordSalt() + "\" }")
    ).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isCreated())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value(admin0.getFirstname()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname").value(admin0.getLastname()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(admin0.getEmail()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login").value(admin0.getLogin()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.password").value(admin0.getPassword()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.passwordSalt").value(admin0.getPasswordSalt()))
    .andExpect(header().string("Location", Matchers.containsString("/admin/")))
    .andReturn();
}
```

For example, I could send a GET request on the newly created resource.

Then I could do a DELETE request on it and end with a GET one once again.

Is that a sensible integration test scenario ?

For this, I would need to retrieve the id of the created resource.

Any way to do this ?

Thank you !

Stephane

Comment: Everything is possible... Depends on what you return. In general when you return a 201 (created), the link to retrieve the resource should be in the Location header. But as stated it depends on how you implemented yuor controller/service.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes my Location header is like http://localhost/admin/625 and I can see it. The Redirected URL is also like http://localhost/admin/625 I think what I should try to do is to extract that URL and use it in a GET and a DELETE requests.

Comment: Then you can use that Location header and do a GET and/or DELETE request. You are basically simulating your client this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve it by doing so:

MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(...).andReturn();

The andReturn() call is there to return the value into the result variable.

String location = result.getResponse().getHeader("Location");

Now I can do a test with the following scenario: POST (created), GET (found), DELETE (ok), GET (not found)

Here is the whole test:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Common.createAuthenticationHeaders("stephane" + ":" + PASSWORD);

MvcResult resultPost = this.mockMvc.perform(
    post("/admin").headers(httpHeaders)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content("{ \"firstname\" : \"" + admin0.getFirstname() + "\", \"lastname\" : \"" + admin0.getLastname() + "\", \"email\" : \"" + admin0.getEmail() + "\", \"login\" : \"" + admin0.getLogin() + "\", \"password\" : \"" + admin0.getPassword() + "\", \"passwordSalt\" : \"" + admin0.getPasswordSalt() + "\" }")
).andDo(print())
.andExpect(status().isCreated())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value(admin0.getFirstname()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname").value(admin0.getLastname()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(admin0.getEmail()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.login").value(admin0.getLogin()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.password").value(admin0.getPassword()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.passwordSalt").value(admin0.getPasswordSalt()))
.andExpect(header().string("Location", Matchers.containsString("/admin/")))
.andReturn();

String location = resultPost.getResponse().getHeader("Location");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(location);
matcher.find();
Long id = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(), 10);

MvcResult resultGet = this.mockMvc.perform(
        get("/admin/" + id)
        .headers(httpHeaders)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isFound())
        .andReturn();
String responseContent = resultGet.getResponse().getContentAsString();

this.mockMvc.perform(
        delete("/admin/" + id)
        .headers(httpHeaders)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

this.mockMvc.perform(
        get("/admin/" + id)
        .headers(httpHeaders)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options that I can think of, depending on what you're trying to test.

Simplest and fastest is to mock your user service/repository, or whatever it is that's returning the user details. Using Mockito, you could have code such as:

```
// At start of test, we have an admin user in the mock database
when(userRepo.findOne(1)).thenReturn(myNewAdmin());

// some activities and assertions...

// At this point, we have deleted the admin, so return null.
when(userRepo.findOne(1)).thenReturn(null);

// more activities and assertions...
```

Alternatively, if you are trying to fully integration test your application, and you're using JPA, then it's relatively simple to define an embedded in-memory database, implemented by something such as HSQLDB or H2. Here you need to define a separate datasources and entity managers in the test context, and configure Hibernate (in test context) to generate schema entities which don't exist. This way you can test inserting entities into the database and whether their IDs are generated correctly, query for them, update them and delete them. All within your build process.

I knocked up a demo app which does this just recently, which you can find in GitHub:

https://github.com/gratiartis/multids-demo

... although it's demonstrating the use of multiple datasources, so there are probably simpler tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at your tutorial and it seems to be more focusing on the configuration of testing. I'm trying to extract the URL from the Response header. The mockMvc makes it easy to print out the whole response in the console log, but I wonder how to extract that URL so as to use it further down the road in my test.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a deletehandler to delete the item from the database immediately after the test.

Use the deleteHandler in your test:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post(...)).andDo(deleteResult(repository));
```

And create the following class somewhere in your `/src/test/java` structure:

```
public class DeleteResultHandler implements ResultHandler {

    private CrudRepository<IDatabaseObject, String> repository;

    public DeleteResultHandler(CrudRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public static DeleteResultHandler deleteResult(CrudRepository repository) {
        return new DeleteResultHandler(repository);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
        String location = result.getResponse().getHeader("Location");
        String id = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        Optional<IDatabaseObject> o = repository.findById(id);
        if (!o.isPresent())
            return;
        repository.delete(o.get());
        // repository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```